# Probability of x edges in a G(n,p) model

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

(i)  Define the two Erd ̋os–R ́enyi models, $G(n,m)$ and $G(n,p)$, of random graphs.

(ii)  For  a  fixed  value  of $n$,  describe  each  of  the  two  models  as  a  probability distribution on the set $G_n$ of all graphs on the $n$ nodes $X=\{1,2,...,n\}$.

(iii)  For $n=100$ and $p=\frac{1}{99}$, what is the probability that a graph G sampled from the $G(n,p)$ model has exactly 50 edges?

For (iii) what I've done is:

$$P = \binom{\binom{100}{2}}{50}*\left(\frac{1}{99}\right)^{50}*\left(\frac{98}{99}\right)^{\binom{100}{2}-50}.$$

Is my thinking correct? I know the expected edges is 50 via the formula.

Comment: If you mean $p=1/99$ instead of $p=199$, then your expression for the probability looks right.

Comment: Yeah you're right thanks!